# install a node red module from a git repo

Tags: node-modules, node-red

for node red, how do you install a node?

I downloaded some [code from github](https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/tree/main/examples/NodeRed) that is for node red and placed the contents in this directory:

`~/.node-red/node_modules/volttron`

Looks like this:
[image]

How do I install it, so I can pull the module out of the node red pallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions included in that directory say to place the files in the `~/.node-red/nodes/volttron` directory (you will need to make the `nodes` dir) not `~/.node-red/node_modules/volttron`. But even then it won't work out of the box as it requires the `python-shell` npm module to also be installed.

A slightly better approach will be to do the following:

Copy the files to `~/.node-red/node_modules/volttron`.

In order for Node-RED to locate the nodes in the `node_modules` directory there must be a `package.json` file. This also needs to include `node-red` section listing the nodes.

The `package.json` also needs to include the required pre-requisite modules in this case `python-shell`

As a short term work around you can create a `package.json` in the `~/.node-red/node_modules/volttron` directory with the other files and containing the following:

```
{
    "name"         : "volttron",
    "version"      : "0.0.1",
    "description"  : "A sample node for node-red",
    "dependencies": {
        "python-shell": "^3.0.1"
    },
    "keywords": [ "node-red" ],
    "node-red"     : {
        "nodes": {
            "volttron": "volttron.js"
        }
    }
}
```

Then run `npm install` while in the volttron directory. You will need to restart Node-RED for the node to be discovered

Comment: Thanks when you say `npm install` in the `volttron` directory, thats this directory right? `~/.node-red/nodes/volttron`

Comment: Yes, that is the easiest option.

Comment: Any chance you could help with this too? Taking it one step further more errors and not sure where even start troubleshooting... Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70327388/typeerror-pythonshell-is-not-a-constructor

Answer (score 1):

The repository you link to includes a readme with instructions for how to install it. Nowhere does it say to copy anything into the node_modules directory.

Step one says:

> Copy all files from `volttron/examples/NodeRed` to  your `.node-red/nodes`
> directory.