# TypeError: PythonShell is not a constructor

Tags: node-red, volttron

I am experimenting with a node red - VOLTTRON (Python framework) [integration](https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/tree/main/examples/NodeRed) where I am hoping to view the VOLTTRON message bus in Node Red.

When I do the appropriate steps as defined in the README like copying the files over to the correct `~/.node-red/nodes/volttron` and getting the correct VOLTTRON authentication keys

When I start Node Red, I get an error:

```
12 Dec 14:07:54 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
12 Dec 14:07:54 - [info] Starting flows
12 Dec 14:07:54 - [info] Started flows
12 Dec 14:07:54 - [warn] [volttron-input:03074cce8abc3174] /home/ben/.node-red/nodes/volttron
12 Dec 14:07:54 - [warn] [volttron-input:03074cce8abc3174] /home/ben/.node-red/nodes/volttron/node_red_subscriber.py
12 Dec 14:07:54 - [red] Uncaught Exception:
12 Dec 14:07:54 - TypeError: PythonShell is not a constructor
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/ben/.node-red/nodes/volttron/volttron.js:33:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

I am unsure if this would be a problem associated with javascript or Python? Thanks for any tips next to zero wisdom here.

volttron.js

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
    // Set these variables to be valid file paths
    var volttron_env = '/home/ben/.volttron';
    var volttron_home = '/home/ben/Desktop/volttron';
    var python_path = '/usr/lib/python3.8';

    function VolttronInputNode(config) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this,config);
        var node = this;
        var pyshell = null;
        this.on('close', function(done) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                /* do some asynchronous cleanup before calling done */
                if (pyshell && !pyshell.terminated && pyshell.childProcess)
                    pyshell.childProcess.kill('SIGINT');
                done();
            });
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
            process.env['VIRTUAL_ENV'] = volttron_env;
            process.env['VOLTTRON_HOME'] = volttron_home;
            var options = {
                mode: 'json',
                pythonPath: python_path,
                scriptPath: __dirname,
            };
            var path = require('path');
            node.warn(__dirname);
            var scriptName = 'node_red_subscriber.py';
            var scriptPath = path.resolve(__dirname, scriptName);
            node.warn(scriptPath);
            pyshell = new PythonShell(scriptName, options);

            pyshell.on('message', function (data) {
                msg = {};
                msg.topic = node.name;
                msg.payload = data;
                node.send(msg);
            });

            pyshell.end(function (err) {
                node.error(err);
            });

        });
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType("volttron-input", VolttronInputNode);

    function VolttronOutputNode(config) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this,config);
        var node = this;
        this.on('close', function(done) {
            setTimeout(function() { /* do some asynchronous cleanup before calling done */ done(); });
        });
        this.on("input", function (msg) {
            setTimeout(function() { // send asynchronously
                var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
                process.env['VIRTUAL_ENV'] = volttron_env;
                process.env['VOLTTRON_HOME'] = volttron_home;
                var options = {
                    mode: 'json',
                    pythonPath: python_path,
                    scriptPath: __dirname,
                    args: [msg.payload.topic, msg.payload.data]
                };
                var path = require('path');
                var scriptName = 'node_red_publisher.py';
                var scriptPath = path.resolve(__dirname, scriptName);
                PythonShell.run(scriptName, options, function(err, result) {
                    if (err) node.error(err);
                    if (result) node.warn(result);
                });
            });

        });
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType("volttron-output",VolttronOutputNode);

}
```

node_red_subscriber.py

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import sys


import gevent

from volttron.platform.messaging import headers as headers_mod
from volttron.platform.vip.agent import Agent, PubSub, Core
from volttron.platform.agent import utils
from volttron.platform.scheduling import periodic
from volttron.platform import jsonapi

from settings import topic_prefixes_to_watch, heartbeat_period, agent_kwargs


class NodeRedSubscriber(Agent):

    def onmessage(self, peer, sender, bus, topic, headers, message):
        d = {'topic': topic,
             'headers': headers,
             'message': message}
        sys.stdout.write(jsonapi.dumps(d)+'\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()

    @Core.receiver('onstart')
    def onstart(self, sender, **kwargs):
        for prefix in topic_prefixes_to_watch:
            self.vip.pubsub.subscribe(peer='pubsub', prefix=prefix, callback=self.onmessage).get(timeout=10)

    # Demonstrate periodic decorator and settings access
    @Core.schedule(periodic(heartbeat_period))
    def publish_heartbeat(self):
        now = utils.format_timestamp(datetime.utcnow())
        headers = {
            headers_mod.CONTENT_TYPE: headers_mod.CONTENT_TYPE.PLAIN_TEXT,
            headers_mod.DATE: now,
            headers_mod.TIMESTAMP: now
        }
        result = self.vip.pubsub.publish('pubsub', 'heartbeat/NodeRedSubscriber', headers, now)
        result.get(timeout=10)


if  __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        # If stdout is a pipe, re-open it line buffered
        if utils.isapipe(sys.stdout):
            # Hold a reference to the previous file object so it doesn't
            # get garbage collected and close the underlying descriptor.
            stdout = sys.stdout
            sys.stdout = os.fdopen(stdout.fileno(), 'w', 1)

        agent = NodeRedSubscriber(identity='NodeRedSubscriber', **agent_kwargs)
        task = gevent.spawn(agent.core.run)

        try:
            task.join()
        finally:
            task.kill()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

***EDIT***
Trying some steps further, in the directory `.node-red/node_modules` I placed one file called `package.json` with the contents provided in the answer with the dependency `"python-shell": "^1.0.4"` as provided in the answer. And then from this same directory running from bash some npm errors come up:

`~/.node-red/node_modules$ npm install volttron`

traceback:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/volttron - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'volttron@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ben/.npm/_logs/2021-12-13T12_52_57_550Z-debug.log
```

In the other directory `~/.node-red/nodes/volttron`

These files are present:

```
node_red_publisher.py  node_red_subscriber.py  README  settings.py  volttron.html  volttron.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70327077/504554) I had to guess which version of `python-shell` was used by the node as it has no hints, so I picked the current latest version (3.0.1) as an arbitrary choice.

It appears that this was the wrong choice soI suggest you edit the `package.json` file again and change the `^3.0.1` version for the `python-shell` dependency and change it to `^1.0.4`

```
{
    "name"         : "volttron",
    "version"      : "0.0.1",
    "description"  : "A sample node for node-red",
    "dependencies": {
        "python-shell": "^1.0.4"
    },
    "keywords": [ "node-red" ],
    "node-red"     : {
        "nodes": {
            "volttron": "volttron.js"
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to run `npm install` again in the `volttron` directory after making the change.

If this is not the case then you will have to take this up with Volttron.

Comment: Would there be any chance you could check out the `edit` I made on my post? Still trying to do the `npm install volttron` but am not doing something right. Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: Delete the `~/.node-red/nodes/volttron` directory. Next why did you add `volttron` to the end of the `npm install` command? I didn't tell you to do that. In the `~/.node-red/node_modules/volttron` directory run just `npm install` (after making the change to `package.json`)

Comment: OK that makes sense now sorry, I definitely understand! `found 0 vulnerabilities` What is the next steps? Do I still have to do these next steps as they mention in the README on VOLTTRON: `Installation:

Copy all files from 'volttron/examples/NodeRed' to  your '.node-red/nodes
directory.`

Comment: Re-read the answer to the other question. The instructions from volttron are wrong and will never work properly.

Comment: Would you have any suggestions I could relay to the VOLTTRON developers?

Comment: https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/issues/2838

Comment: Thank you so much ill keep an eye on this.